# Why does my Live-USB fail to boot with "Syslinux..."?

Tags: boot, live-usb, syslinux

I having trouble getting to boot from a Live USB pendrive explained in Ubuntu.com website. I downloaded various ISO images and only had success in booting from Live a CD or DVD.

I've gotten newer hardware which it should be able to boot from USB. I set the BIOS option to boot from USB FDD first and I get something like in the following scene but it remains stuck in: `Syslinux... Peter Avin`.

I tried booting from USB with [pendrivelinux.com](http://pendrivelinux.com/) and UNetbootin on my older machine before and I have never been able to do it successfully. In fact the only time I was able to boot a Linux distro through USB was Puppy Linux and back then I had to do a legacy Puppy Linux option done to the USB stick for my older hardware to boot from the USB.

Comment: do you want to boot from a usb drive to perform an installation, or is it just a generic question ? I ask because it is possible to boot from an ISO in the hard drive

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/126579/full-install-that-went-well-wont-boot-not-even-from-my-usb-stick-really-confu

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have in the bootable usb a folder called `syslinux` and not `isolinux`. If so, rename it and change `isolinux.bin` to `syslinux.bin` and `isolinux.cfg` to `sysinux.cfg`;  you'll find them in the `syslinux` folder.